# Optimizing MySql query to avoid using "Using filesort"

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, filesort

I need your help to optimize the query to **avoid using** "Using filesort".The job of the query is to select all the articles that belongs to specific tag. The query is:

```
  select title 
    from tag,
         article 
   where tag = 'Riyad' 
     AND tag.article_id = article.id 
order by tag.article_id
```

The tables structure are the following:

Tag table

```
 CREATE TABLE `tag` (
 `tag` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
 `article_id` INT NOT NULL ,
 KEY `tag` (`tag`),
 KEY `article_id` (`article_id`)
 ) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Article table

```
 CREATE TABLE `article` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `title` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Sample data

```
 INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (1, 'About Riyad');
 INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (2, 'About Newyork');
 INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (3, 'About Paris');
 INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (4, 'About London');

 INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Riyad', 1);
 INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Saudia', 1);
 INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Newyork', 2);
 INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('USA', 2);
 INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Paris', 3);
 INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('France', 3);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In table `tag`, replace the key on `tag` with a key on (`tag`, `article_id`):

```
ALTER TABLE `tag` DROP INDEX `tag`, ADD INDEX `tag_article_id` (`tag`, `article_id`)
```

MySQL will only use one index on a table to perform a query. At present, it is using the index on `tag`, but cannot use the other index to perform the ORDER BY. If you put the second column in the index then it will use it to help with the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

You're joining, in part, on `tag.article_id=article.id`, but don't have an index in place on the tag side to support that optimally. Add a secondary (non-unique) index on `tag.article_id`.

Comment: I did but the same problem exists. It use file sort because of "order by". If I delete order by it works fine. thanks for help Dave